# Apache Reverse Proxy to a Wordpress site passes subpath when it shouldn't

Tags: wordpress, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've been trying to set up a reverse proxy on a main website to a blog site of the url format

example.com/blog -> blog.example.com

example.com/blog is on an Apache instance and in the `httpd.conf` I have added the following.

```
SSLProxyEngine on

ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPassMatch /blog https://blog.example.com
ProxyPassReverse /blog https://blog.example.com
```

This all works but it keeps 404ing. The good news is it is actually reverse proxying correctly because it grabs the 404 page of the blog.

After looking at the apache access logs I found that it is passing the subpath for whatever reason `/blog` to `blog.example.com` so its fetching `blog.example.com/blog`. When users navigate to `/blog`, it does 404 naturally. However, my understanding was when setting up [`ProxyPassReverse`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) is it would make the request at what was specified so in my above case it should be requesting `blog.example.com` and not passing the `/blog` at the end.

Here is the snippet from the documentation that confirms the above in how it should work:

> For example, suppose the local server has address http://example.com/; then

```
ProxyPass /mirror/foo/ http://backend.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /mirror/foo/ http://backend.example.com/
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain backend.example.com public.example.com
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /mirror/foo/
```

> will not only cause a local request for the http://example.com/mirror/foo/bar to be internally converted into a proxy request to http://backend.example.com/bar (the functionality which ProxyPass provides here).

Any ideas why this might be? Worst case I might try to add a redirect or a rewrite so `/blog` goes to the homepage but I do have my permalinks set up in such a way that the `/blog` is in the slug of articles.

FYI I am using Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I was using `ProxyPassMatch` instead of `ProxyPass`. Ugh.